# How to deploy in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created report in ssrs and i want to deploy it in report server but when click on deploy button it asks username and password i don't understand which username and password it is asking i have not created any password while installing reporting service please help me how to do that...any solution would be appreciated greatly..

Please let me know what is that passowrd i need to pass...

[image]

Comment: report server asking you reporting server username or password where your sql server is installed.

Comment: sql server login details..?

Comment: no men your serverpc username and password detail (login credential).

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the report from BIDS then it ask your NT Login details if you do not have proper authentication of server where report is being deployed.

I think you need to try Report Manager Web Tool to deploy your reports however you should be rights to do so.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

in reporting service configuration manager you determine an service account, you can enter that username and password to deploy.
also you can add users in report manager and grant proper permission to them, and then deploy reports with new usernames.